# Make auth with custom user provider from remote API on Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm desperate to use an API as a way to connect users on a Laravel 10 project.

I developed a custom user provider that fetches a token via the remote API (a service that I use and which does not belong to me). This API returns an email, a handle, and an access token and a refresh token.

When I connect via my form, I get a temporary session with the token, but when the page is reloaded, the "retrieveById" method is called and I try to have the token called the "me" method of the form. API to reconstruct a complete User::class object.

I can use sessions but I don't find it clean. I was just wondering why the "retrieveByCredentials" method doesn't return the User::class class as a whole with the data I pass to it...

My User::class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;

class User extends GenericUser
{
    //
}
```

My CustomUserProvider::class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Services\Api\PdsService;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // fetch access token to use with API
        $result = PdsService::factory()->me();

        return new User([
            'id' => $identifier,
            'email' => $result['email'],
            'handle' => $result['handle'],
            'accessToken' => $result['accessJwt'],
            'refreshToken' => $result['refreshJwt'],
        ]);
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        //
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * @param array $credentials
     * @return User|null
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials): ?User
    {
        $identifier = $credentials['identifier'] ?? null;
        $password = $credentials['password'] ?? null;

        if (is_null($identifier) || is_null($password)) {
            return null;
        }

        $result = PdsService::factory()
            ->login($identifier, $password);

        if (!empty($result['error'])) {
            return null;
        }

        return new User([
            'id' => $result['did'],
            'email' => $result['email'],
            'handle' => $result['handle'],
            'accessToken' => $result['accessJwt'],
            'refreshToken' => $result['refreshJwt'],
        ]);
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In boot method in AuthServiceProvider::class :

```
Auth::provider('custom_provider', fn() => new CustomUserProvider);
```

And the auth config file :

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'custom_provider',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Cookie/Header auth

When you return the User model to the FE (frontend), you can store it on the client side and attach it with every next guarded request.

### Data persistency

If you want to persist the data of `retrieveById` in the FE, you can store it in a cookie.

With JS/TS you can access the cookie and use the data in your preferred way in the frontend.

### Credential validation

The bearer token and/or cookie that is attached to the request can be validated in a (custom) middleware.